# pyautogui: messes up with loops

Tags: python, pyautogui

Warning: extremely new to python
So tested out this code. It seems to work individually but when i put it in a loop it appears to mess up. This code is supposed to automate the task of applying for jobs on indeed. Clicks on easily apply, fills out the form and sends.

website: https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=engineer&l=Vancouver%2C%20BC&vjk=565326d05dc048c8

Problem is, when i added the loop so it can apply for more than 1 job per page, it messes up. 2 problems:

1. It takes a long time to execute.
2. when it does, it fills out the phone number in the "name" section, then freezes.

Any help is appreciated. It didn't have these problems when i tested it for a single form submission, and was able to submit the form from start to finish.

```
   import pyautogui, time

pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.click(863,330)

applynow = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("applynow.png")
confirmyourapplication = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("confirmyourapplication.png")
howmanyyears = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("howmanyyears.png")

for i in range (0, 9):
    if applynow == None:
        pyautogui.scroll(-425)
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
    else:
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('applynow.png')
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        pyautogui.typewrite('Jake Williams', 0.25)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        pyautogui.typewrite('jwilliam02@hotmail.com', 0.25)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        pyautogui.typewrite('719-985-3546', 0.25)
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('choosefile.png')
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        pyautogui.typewrite('resume', 0.25)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('continue.png')
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        if confirmyourapplication == None:
            if howmanyyears == None:
                x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('back.png')
                pyautogui.click(x,y)
                x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('cancle.png')
                pyautogui.click(x,y)
                pyautogui.scroll(-425)
                x, y = pyautogui.position()
                pyautogui.click(x,y)
            else:
                print('pause here')
                time.sleep(1000)
        else:
            x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('apply.png')
            pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the website?

Comment: https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=engineer&l=Vancouver%2C%20BC&vjk=565326d05dc048c8

I apologize!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I would like to add a comment and request that this question be closed. It turns out that i was previously testing it on chrome and was careless when switching to firefox. However, if anyone can explain why the loop takes to long to process, that would be appretiated, it is approximately a 30 second wait.

Comment: In `pyautogui.typewrite('Jake Williams', 0.25)` the 0.25 means wait 0.25 seconds between each keystroke, so `Jake Williams` takes 3.25 seconds to type, overall just the typing in the the example takes 13.25 seconds.

Comment: yes i'm aware of that. the typing takes a while. But it takes a long time to initialize the loop. it does the first click quickly `pyautogui.click(863,330)`. Then just waits for like 30 seconds before it starts clicking on the forums and typing.

Comment: Have you tried timing how long those `locateOnScreen()` function calls take?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following just after the neccessary imports:

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
```

that should solve it :)